# Changing projection of TIFF in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.4

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 I have a TIFF which is projected in WGS84 and displays the whole world, with the center is the Atlantic Ocean.

I would like to display the Pacific Ocean in the center, not the Atlantic Ocean.

But I can't change the coordinate system because I have much more information I'd like to merge with the basemap.

Comment: Your meaning is unclear. There are a number of questions which detail the procedure for cutting a GCS image in half and appending the left side after the right (or right after left) with different packages, but the "much more information" adds complexity without any way to resolve them without more details.

Comment: Then you reproject the other data to a Pacific-centered projection as well before creating the basemap.

Comment: To do this you have to modify your raster.  You'll have to cut it and join it with the pacific positioned how you want it.  This is not a projection issue.  Use WGS84 and adjust your central meridian to around 170 W